# Admob stops serving Ads to my iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob

Today, I receive this email from Admob. My app is passcode lock for Facebook web view. I integrate Admob banner and interstitial ads in the app. The user navigation is definitely friendly and easy reflected in the reviews. The users like my app. Has this happened to anyone here? How do I go about appealing this disabling? Thanks

> Hello, This email is to alert you that one of your applications is not
>   currently in compliance with our AdMob program policies and as a
>   result, ad serving has been disabled to your application.
>
> Issue ID#: xxxxx
>
> Ad serving has been disabled to: xxxxxxxx
>
> Action required: Check all other remaining applications in your
>   account for compliance.
>
> Current account status: Active
>
> Violation explanation
>
> It is important for an application displaying AdMob to offer
>   significant value to the user by providing unique and relevant
>   content, and not to place ads on auto-generated pages or pages with
>   little to no original content.
>
> Your application should also provide a good user experience through
>   clear navigation and organization. Users should be able to easily
>   click through your pages and find the information they are seeking.
>
> For more information, please review the AdMob program policies and
>   Google’s Webmaster Quality Guidelines.
>
> Action required: Check account for compliance While ad serving has
>   been disabled to the above app, your AdMob account remains active. We
>   suggest that you take the time to review the rest of your applications
>   to ensure that they’re in compliance with our policies, and to monitor
>   your apps accordingly to reduce the likelihood of future policy emails
>   from us. Additionally, please note that our team reserves the right to
>   disable accounts at any time if we continue to see violations
>   occurring.
>
> Appeals If you wish to appeal this disabling then you can do so by
>   using our appeal form.
>
> Thank you for your cooperation.
>
> Sincerely,
>
> The Google AdMob Team